# Perl - Need to append duplicates in a file and write unique value only

Tags: perl, duplicates, append

I have searched a fair bit and hope I'm not duplicating something someone has already asked.   I have what amounts to a CSV that is specifically formatted (as required by a vendor).   There are four values that are being delimited as follows:

```
"Name","Description","Tag","IPAddresses"
```

The list is quite long (and there are ~150 unique names--only 2 in the sample below) but it basically looks like this:

```
"2B_AppName-Environment","desc","tag","192.168.1.1"
"2B_AppName-Environment","desc","tag","192.168.22.155"
"2B_AppName-Environment","desc","tag","10.20.30.40"
"6G_ServerName-AltEnv","desc","tag","1.2.3.4"
"6G_ServerName-AltEnv","desc","tag","192.192.192.40"
"6G_ServerName-AltEnv","desc","tag","192.168.50.5"
```

I am hoping for a way in Perl (or sed/awk, etc.) to come up with the following:

```
"2B_AppName-Environment","desc","tag","192.168.1.1,192.168.22.155,10.20.30.40"
"6G_ServerName-AltEnv","desc","tag","1.2.3.4,192.192.192.40,192.168.50.5"
```

So basically, the resulting file will APPEND the duplicates to the first match -- there should only be one line per each app/server name with a list of comma-separated IP addresses just like what is shown above.

Note that the "Decription" and "Tag" fields don't need to be considered in the duplication removal/append logic -- let's assume these are blank for the example to make things easier.   Also, in the vendor-supplied list, the "Name" entries are all already sorted to be together.

Comment: Loop through data, using a hash to store info, seems a good way to go.

Comment: Good suggestion and a friend told me similar, but my perl is not strong and I have a deliverable around this that's due very soon.  Hoping for some code examples on how to do that.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Do you require a match on the `desc` and `tag` fields as well? Are records with the same `name` all grouped together?

Comment: I'd ideally like a match on the desc and tag fields as well but if it is too complicated, I will leave it blank for the deliverable as it's optional right now.   The name records are sorted and all appear together (on different lines of course--as shown).  Thanks so much for the quick replies guys!

Comment: Actually, Borodin, after reviewing the data "desc" will always be blank so we don't need to match there.  "tag" will only be one of two values and since it directly aligns, it doesn't need to be matched either.   Let's just go with Name and IPAddresses as the key values.

Comment: @KurtW: Understood. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short Perl program should suit you. It expects the path to the input CSV file as a parameter on the command line and prints the result to `STDOUT`. It keeps track of the appearance of new `name` fields in the `@names` array so that it can print the output in the order that each name first appears, and it takes the values for `desc` and `tag` from the *first* occurrence of each unique `name`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({always_quote => 1, eol => "\n"});

my (@names, %data);

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
  my $name = $row->[0];
  if ($data{$name}) {
    $data{$name}[3] .= ','.$row->[3];
  }
  else {
    push @names, $name;
    $data{$name} = $row;
  }
}

for my $name (@names) {
  $csv->print(*STDOUT, $data{$name});
}
```

**output**

```
"2B_AppName-Environment","desc","tag","192.168.1.1,192.168.22.155,10.20.30.40"
"6G_ServerName-AltEnv","desc","tag","1.2.3.4,192.192.192.40,192.168.50.5"
```

---

**Update**

Here's a version that ignores any record that doesn't have a valid IPv4 address in the fourth field. I've used [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Common) as it's the simplest way to get complex regex patterns right. It may need installing on your system.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Regexp::Common;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({always_quote => 1, eol => "\n"});

my (@names, %data);

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
  my ($name, $address) = @{$row}[0,3];
  next unless $address =~ $RE{net}{IPv4};

  if ($data{$name}) {
    $data{$name}[3] .= ','.$address;
  }
  else {
    push @names, $name;
    $data{$name} = $row;
  }
}

for my $name (@names) {
  $csv->print(*STDOUT, $data{$name});
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice at first that all of the IP addresses should be joined together in the same fourth field. It's fixed now. (Are you sure you want it like that? It requires an additional step to separate the addresses once you have extracted the fields.)

Comment: Yep, that's the key!  Need to have all of the IP addresses joined together in the 4th field.   Thank you SO much for your time here... this is making my day.

Comment: @KurtW: You're welcome, but you can't have much of the day left!

Comment: INCREDIBLE!  It works perfectly -- thank you so much.  Marking this as the accepted answer.  Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Hey Borodin, I know this is a side-request but is it possible to disguard a single string when it is seen in the IPAddresses column?  I'd like to exclude "3(NXDOMAIN)" from our tool so it doesn't choke and only receives good input (of IP addresses).  Blanks are okay but this string is rejected.  Just as good, replacing all occurences of "3(NXDOMAIN)" with "127.0.0.1" works, too.  Thanks regardless!

Comment: @KurtW: Do you mean that some of the lines in the file have `"3(NXDOMAIN)"` as the fourth field and you want to ignore it? I think I would rather check that the field looked like an IP4 address and ignore it if not. Would that be okay? If you would *rather* have it replaced with `127.0.0.1` then please say so as either way is simple

Comment: Mods--I would have moved this to chat but my rep is not high enough yet to chat with Borodin.  Sorry, not trying to trail on.  Borodin, that is perfectly fine--and yes, I am refering to the 4th field only.  The field cannot be empty, cannot be simply '0', and cannot contain "3(NXDOMAIN)".  I'm fine replacing those 3 terms with 127.0.0.1 if that's easier.  Thank you *so* much.

Comment: It's 01:08am in England so I'm going to bed. I've added an update to my solution that just ignores any input that doesn't have a valid IP address. If you need something different then I'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use a CSV parser like [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) for this type of problem.

`Borodin` has already pasted a good example of how to do this.

One of the approaches that I'd advise you **NOT** to use are regular expressions.

The following one-liner demonstrates how one could do this, but this is a very fragile approach compared to an actual csv parser:

```
perl -0777 -ne '
    while (m{^((.*)"[^"\n]*"\n(?:(?=\2).*\n)*)}mg) {
      $s = $1;
      $s =~ s/"\n.*"([^"\n]+)(?=")/,$1/g;
      print $s
    }' test.csv
```

Outputs:

```
"2B_AppName-Environment","desc","tag","192.168.1.1,192.168.22.155,10.20.30.40"
"6G_ServerName-AltEnv","desc","tag","1.2.3.4,192.192.192.40,192.168.50.5"
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurp the entire file
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `while (m{^((.*)"[^"]*"\n(?:(?=\2).*\n)*)}mg)`: Separate text into matching sections.
- `$s =~ s/"\n.*"([^"\n]+)(?=")/,$1/g;`: Join all ip addresses by a comma in matching sections.
- `print $s`: Print the results.

Comment: Do you have masochism on your CV?!

Comment: Thanks Miller -- very helpful as well.